# Accented characters strange behaviour - Rstudio

Tags: r, rstudio

When typing accented characters (á, é, í, ó, etc.) in the source section in RStudio, they don't display correctly. I'll give two examples to explain:

When I try typing this:

```
"Ótrúlega óþolandi þegar ég skrifa íslenska stafi."
```

this appears as:

```
"´ótr´úlega ´óþolandi þegar ´ég skrifa ´íslenska stafi"
```

(translation: "Incredibly annoying when I write Icelandic letters.")

When I try typing this:

```
"ááóóééíía"
```

this appears as:

```
"´á´áá´ááó´ááóó´ááóóé´ááóóéé´ááóóééí´ááóóééíía"
```

(translation: This is nonsense...)

I have no idea why this is happening. I'm using RStudio on Mac. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What does `sessionInfo()` tell you about your locale?

Comment: @G5W 
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Sierra 10.12.6


locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.3.2

Comment: you should write special characters as "\u00e9" and alike.

Comment: @pachamaltese No, the output of my code is not the problem. The problem is that in the text editor itself, every time I try typing accented characters in the Untitled1.R or markdown.Rmd files, it is as if I had written extra accents (see example 1) or repeated the letters (see example 2). I then have to go and erase all the extra accents and letters that appear. This dampens my workflow significantly, since my language uses a lot of accented characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like this was a bug in RStudio. I installed the latest version of RStudio and this problem disappeared.

Comment: Indeed, this was a bug in the older versions of RStudio (actually brought upon by a macOS update). Upgrading RStudio resolves this issue.